# H.264 encoder filter for DirectShow

Tags: video, h.264, directshow, encoder

I'm trying to record a video using DirectShow and I need an H.264 encoder filter. I've tried to install:

x264vfw

like suggested here:

[how to use x264 encoder with directshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346810/how-to-use-x264-encoder-with-directshow/26347374#26347374?newreg=72fc4f4c877949c599724dacb04d7703)

but using the video compressor enumerator:

```cpp
IEnumMoniker* EnumIterator = nullptr;
if (DeviceDenumerator->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoCompressorCategory, &EnumIterator, 
    0) != S_OK)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

this filter is listed only for 32bit applications. With an x64 application it doesn't appear.

How can I install an x64 version of that video compressor?

Answer (score 3):

For 64-bit applications you need indeed 64-bit version of the filter (also known as `x264vfw64`), for which you would want to take a look at the following note at SourceForge:

> Starting from 40_2491bm_40895 release builds for 64-bit Windows (x264vfw64) where merged into the one installer with builds for 32-bit Windows (x264vfw). So if you want to use the latest version of x264vfw than you should download it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/files/x264vfw/

The [installer referenced there](https://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/files/x264vfw/44_2851bm_44825/) is, hence, supposed to install both 32 and 64 bits versions of the encoder filter.

UPDATE. The non-availability of 64-bit version seems to be a [known problem](https://sourceforge.net/p/x264vfw/bugs/19/). The ticket explains that 64-bit subsystem does not have a wrapper to pick up VFW encoders and installed H.264 compression remains invisible to DirectShow.

I personally don't think that this description is accurate. Indeed, when DirectShow video encoder enumeration is requested, there is a layer that picks up older Video For Windows codecs (such as x264vfw) and exposes them via [AVI Compressor Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318184) wrapper so that DirectShow application could take advantage of such legacy codecs.

> ... enables Video Compression Manager (VCM) codecs to join a filter graph. Each codec appears as a separate instance of the filter.

64-bit subsystem of 64-bit Windows still has this filter (as opposed to statement in ticket resolution). Yet there might be indeed a reason why such compatibility layer is no longer available in 64-bit DirectShow. The current state, as it seems, is that x264vfw developers are aware of the problem and do not have or plan to have a solution for it.

Comment: I've installed it but it doesn't add any Video Compressor for x64. I've tried with the code above and with GraphStudioNext x64, x264 Video Compressor is not listed (with the x32 version I can see a compressor labeled 'x264vfw - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec'). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks something is wrong with this build indeed. I don't see the 64-bit encoder installed/available either (nevertheless the file x264vfw64.dll is installed). Perhaps you could try an earlier build which could possibly be okay.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with an earlier version. Do you know any other solution or any other DirectShow filter to compress video using H.264/MPEG-4 format?

Comment: I am not aware of free and/or widely used DirectShow H.264 encoder. Commerical filters exist. I myself used to developer a DirectShow wrapper over x264 a few times in past because there is no out of the box solution. Presently I would think of using hardware-assisted H.264 encoding (as preferable to software-only x264), as all three major vendors AMD, Intel, Nvidia have respective capabilities in their GPUs. This still needs custom developed wrapper for DirectShow though.